# How to install uWebSockets?

Tags: c++, linux, git, cmake

I am running ubuntu on my window 10 through VMware. Because the Udacity course needs uWebSockets to run the simulator. 
here is the step the class given to install it:

- run `chmod a+x install-linux.sh`

this is the `install-linux.sh` file in the same directory

```
#!/bin/bash
source /etc/os-release || echo 'Warning: /etc/os-release was not found'

if [[ " $ID_LIKE " == *' archlinux '* ]]; then
  sudo pacman -S git libuv openssl gcc cmake make
else
  if [[ ! " $ID_LIKE " == *' debian '* ]]; then
    echo 'Warning: unidentified Linux distribution, assuming Debian-like'
  fi

  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install git libuv1-dev libssl-dev gcc g++ cmake make
fi

git clone https://github.com/uWebSockets/uWebSockets 
cd uWebSockets
git checkout e94b6e1
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make 
sudo make install
cd ../..
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libuWS.so /usr/lib/libuWS.so
sudo rm -r uWebSockets
```

But when I try the command in the terminal, nothing happened. 
Is anybody can provide some help?

Comment: uwebsocket does not have a cmake file.

Answer (score 0):

All `chmod a+x install-linux.sh` does is change the file permissions of `install-linux.sh` so that it is executable. So I wouldn't expect to see anything in the terminal.

I expect that after changing the file permissions that you are supposed to run the script like this

```
./install-linux.sh
```