# Correct way to install and run uWebSockets in C++

Tags: ubuntu, networking, installation, uwebsockets

What is the recommended way to install the library uWebSockets (https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets) and be able to compile the accompanying examples ?
I have tried the solution provided here: [How to install uWebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832204/how-to-install-uwebsockets) with no success:
I ran the file install-linux.sh (see link above), the installation worked (no error message).
Then, when I try to compile the example HelloWorld.cpp (see https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/blob/master/examples/HelloWorld.cpp), with:

```
g++ -std=c++17 HelloWorld.cpp
```

I get:

```
HelloWorld.cpp:1:10: fatal error: App.h: no such file or directory
```

So, my questions are:

1. How do I correctly install the library,
2. What exact command should I use to compile the examples ?

I am using g++ with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Yes, but by doing so (signaling all necessary paths to g++)  the example does not compile, I get multiple "undefined references" , for example the first one: HelloWorld.cpp:(.text._ZN3uWS15DeflationStreamD2Ev[_ZN3uWS15DeflationStreamD5Ev]+0x18) : undefined reference to « deflateEnd »
That is why I am asking about the correct recommended way to install the library.

Comment: Undefined references means that you actually succeeded in compiling. It's the linking that failed. Did you build and install µSockets (which seems to be a prerequisite)? You need to link with that library (or those libraries) too. I assume you tried `WITH_OPENSSL=1 make examples` too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules git@github.com:uNetworking/uWebSockets.git
cd uWebSockets
WITH_OPENSSL=1 make examples
```

It built all examples, including `HelloWorld`, clean.

If you want to use WolfSSL instead, then make the examples using this instead:

```
WITH_WOLFSSL=1 WITH_LIBUV=1 make examples
```

If you want to install the `uWebSockets` header files together with other libraries you've downloaded:

```
make DESTDIR=$HOME/.local prefix= install
```

The `uSocket` sub module doesn't seem to get installed - or have a proper installation procedure so you'll have to do some digging to find out which headers are needed (if any). Building the examples produced some `uSocket` libraries though:

```
./uSockets/boringssl/util/ar/testdata/linux/libsample.a
./uSockets/boringssl/util/ar/testdata/mac/libsample.a
./uSockets/uSockets.a
```

These should probably be copied to where you store other third party libraries (`$HOME/.local/lib` perhaps). I assume you need to link your `uWebSockets` apps with `uSockets.a`. You can probably figure out how by looking at the examples.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete working installation procedure, will all necessary packages (like uWebSockets which seems to be required), with the paths where usually such libraries are installed ?

Comment: @Henry What I showed is complete. I started from scratch and cloned the uWebSockets repo and build it just like I showed in the answer. What problem do you get? Update your question instead of having us guess.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that the examples had been built. They seem to work fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Henry Great, you're welcome!

Comment: The provided examples are a bit thechnical for my level of understanding. Would you know of a tutorial for setting up a web socket connection from scratch using uWebSockets from a C++ code ? Let's say I know the URL and I just need to setup the connection and print the output messages ?

Comment: @Henry No, but I would pick one of the examples where a client is created and just modify that to get the hang of it.

Comment: I was expecting to find uWS.h file ... but it's not there

Comment: @Paul [uWebSockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets) does not contain a file called `uWS.h`. Where did your expectation come from?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was following some recipes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602032/can-a-c-uwebsockets-server-communicate-with-a-javascript-client

Comment: @Paul It seems there was a `uWS.h` in the library a long time ago but [it's been removed](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/discussions/1082). If you `git checkout v0.14` (which is from 2018) you will have it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo also ChatGPT give me some examples with the line #include <uWS/uWS.h>

Comment: @Paul ChatGPT is not a very good source when it comes to solving programming issues. I've tried it out for fun and it nearly never gives correct answers to my questions.